# How do I run "python manage.py migrate" in a Visual Studio Django Web Project?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I am trying to run the default Django Web Project using Visual Studio 2022. I have reached this point:

[image]

I open a Developer PowerShell window and run "python manage.py migrate". However, this fails because manage.py is in a sub-directory.

So I run "python DjangoWebProject\manage.py migrate". This fails with "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?"

What should I do to get this working?

Comment: Are you using docker? What is the IDE? Most importantly, how are you loading your system to begin with?...the short is you need to get into your execution env to run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands...there are simple ways to place models in separate directories, with properly imported models in  `__init__` files but I can't tell if that is your issue

Comment: " Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?": do you have the environment Django's installed in activated? If you ran Django in that one terminal, you should be able to just `ctrl+c` that running server, then run `migrate` like you were.